# read single character not first character with scanf/sscanf. (not %c)

Tags: c, scanf

I want to have a problem that itś able to distinguish when the user inputs a char or a string. For example:

Given the input "A", then letter="A";
Given the input "ABC", then discard;

I want to be able to distinguish when the two cases happen, so that I can discard when the user inputs a string versus a single letter.

By now, I have the following code written in C:

```
char letter;
sscanf("%c",&letter);
scanf("%c",&letter):
```

With the code above, what I get is:

Given the input "A", then letter="A";
Given the input "ABC", then letter="A;

How can i make this work?

Comment: Read a string, check the length, and discard it if it isn't one character long.

Comment: Read a whole line with `fgets()`, then count the number of characters in it. If it's more than 1 character (not counting the newline at the end), discard it.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean with "discard". Do you want to reject the input and reprompt the user if the input is larger than a single character? Or do you want to simply exit the program with an error message in that case? Or do you want to discard all characters except for the first one?

Comment: **Always** read a line with `fgets`, then parse it. It doesn't matter what kind of input you expect.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to read an entire line of input as a string using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then to check the length of the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[200];

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter input: " );

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remove newline character, if it exists
    line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = '\0';

    //check number of characters in input
    switch ( strlen( line ) )
    {
        case 0:
            printf( "The line is empty!\n" );
            break;
        case 1:
            printf( "The line contains only a single character.\n" );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "The input contains several characters.\n" );
            break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter input: 
The line is empty!
```

```
Please enter input: a
The line contains only a single character.
```

```
Please enter input: ab
The input contains several characters.
```

Comment: The only one who knew why strlen(x) == 1 will not work

Comment: Upvote is well deserved!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    char letter[128];

    if (fgets(letter, 128, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        letter[strcspn(letter,"\n")] = '\0'; // remove newline character if present
        if (strlen(letter) > 1)
        {
            letter[0] = '\0'; // empty the string
            // memset(letter,0,sizeof(letter)); also empties the array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work in a real program, it does in godbolt because it has specific stdin handling. https://godbolt.org/z/77x4aK6Y9

Comment: @0___________ Is it because of the missing check for/removal of the newline character?

Comment: @0___________ I've edited my answer and handled ```\n``` character. Thanks for spotting the mistake in my code!

Answer (score -3):

You can get it to work if you use fgets instead of scanf.
With ***char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)*** you get the string from the stream stdin.
And then you use strlen to get its size.
If it is greater than 2 (for size 2 we have the character itself and the newline character) you set the value of the string to "\0".

Basically:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(){
 char str[128];
 fgets(str, 128, stdin);
    
 if(strlen(str)>2)
    str[0]='\0';
   
return 0;

}
```